# Update GSI of DynamoDB, old data not update in new GSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have one table, name is Ticket

Ticket {
id,
usage,
affiliationOrganization
createdAt,
....
}

GSI1:
PartionKey: usage
SortKey: affiliationOrganization

After a development time, i want update SortKey of GSI1
PartionKey: usage
SortKey: affiliationOrganization#createdAt

But after modifying the GSI, the old data is no longer in this GSI table.
Only when adding new data will these new data be automatically typed into the GSI table.

(My english is stupid, I'm sorry if I wrote it wrong)

I want to automatically update old data to GSI after it is modified
Avoid data loss in GSI table, query is not missing data

Answer (score 0):

The old data will automatically replicate to the GSI should it be eligible. Please ensure all your old items have an attribute named `affiliationOrganization#createdAt`.

Note that this must be a single attribute, DynamoDB does not combine attributes automatically, you must do so manually.